# Is it possible to add a potentiometer instead of a fixed resistor to control negative feedback?

Tags: amplifier, tube

Here you see the circuit of my tube amplifier. Is it possible to replace the resistor with a 250k potentiometer to control the negative feedback, or can it cause some other problems?

[image]

Comment: you drew a variable resistor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is yes, you ***can*** replace the feedback resistor with a pot, but you don't explain ***why*** you want to do it. What are you hoping to achieve?
You should add a fixed resistor in series with the pot, say 10K, so that you cannot reduce the FB resistance to zero.
Too much or too little feedback may cause instability or distortion so be careful what you wish for. The original circuit should already be optimised for best performance.

Comment: I red a lot in internet, that removing the negative feedback in a tube amp for guitar makes the tone more ruff, and the distortion breakup gets better. Right now as far as i understand the negative feedback makes the sound more smooth. I would like to adjust the sound to my taste.

Comment: I measured a potentiometer and it never gets to zero value. Thee is always a minimum resistence

Comment: A few ohms is 0Ω as compared to 33kΩ.  Take Peter's advice and add a resistor in series with the pot.  Or understand the circuit enough that what is the impact of 0Ω on the feedback circuit.  Avoids letting the magic smoke out.

Comment: Yes you are right. Few ohms are nearly zero compared to 33kΩ. Resistor in series is good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

As the wiper moves on a potentiometer, it may 'jump' off the track briefly. If there is DC current in the pot, this could cause noise in the audio system. In addition, to be 'safe', the 3rd terminal of the pot is usually connected to the wiper, so that even if the wiper lifts off, the maximum resistance is well controlled.

Comment: shouldn't the 3rd terminal connect to ground? Would be a switch between different resistor values be better to reduce noise?

Comment: Not ground -- connect the 3rd terminal to the wiper (middle terminal). The pot only makes noise sometimes when it is being moved; a switch would make large 'clunks' when changing.